# Use WebAudio's clock to schedule Cordova's function

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, web-audio-api, wavesurfer.js

I'm starting my programming studies with a Android Cordova app music player, where I need to play several local files at the exact same time.

Currently, I'm using [Wavesurfer.js](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js) (Web Audio API based) to do that, but I'm strugling with some issues: it takes a few seconds to load each mp3 file and it crashes the app after some files are loaded (it's not releasing the memory after the files are played).

With [Cordova Media Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media), I can load the files much faster than with Web Audio, I have no memory issues, but I can't schedule the files to play at the same time.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46101403/use-web-audio-api-clock-for-executing-callbacks-or-throwing-events?newreg=a2159921b9994dd8aa8fc9c65d3dcbf6) trick to play the files via Cordova's plugin, but I'm having around 900ms delay between the 1st and the 20th file (they are 14" length, 231KB size).

According to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode), I could use an AudioWorkletNode to play the files directly from disk, but I cant't find a way to achieve that.

Any ideas how should I approach this issue?

Thanks in advance.